# Is there a way to prevent basic auth from popping inside iframe other than white list?

Tags: html, security, iframe, basic-authentication

I'm looking for a way to forbid basic auth from popping inside an iframe and the only option I see is the creation of a white list inside the CSP but it doesn't suit my needs. Are there any other options available? Sandbox in iframe can't forbid basic auth to go through obviously.